# My function that creates a dictionary from a list, is repeating the values three times instead of just once

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a function that is supposed to take a list of top 10 baby names from 1980-1984 and a empty dictionary as arguments, and it's supposed to return a dictionary with the name as the key and a list of lists with the frequency, gender, and year as values.

The data list looks something like this:

```
  ...[1, 'Christopher', 741, 'Boy', 1984],
  [2, 'Michael', 674, 'Boy', 1984],
  [3, 'Matthew', 630, 'Boy', 1984],
  [4, 'Ryan', 598, 'Boy', 1984],
  [5, 'Daniel', 459, 'Boy', 1984],
  [6, 'David', 413, 'Boy', 1984],
  [7, 'Jason', 399, 'Boy', 1984],
  [8, 'Andrew', 343, 'Boy', 1984],
  [8, 'Robert', 343, 'Boy', 1984],
  [10, 'Kyle', 331, 'Boy', 1984],
  [1, 'Jennifer', 705, 'Girl', 1980],
  [2, 'Amanda', 551, 'Girl', 1980],
  [3, 'Melissa', 316, 'Girl', 1980],
  [4, 'Lisa', 290, 'Girl', 1980],
  [5, 'Sarah', 284, 'Girl', 1980],
  [6, 'Michelle', 281, 'Girl', 1980],
  [7, 'Nicole', 252, 'Girl', 1980],
  [8, 'Erin', 249, 'Girl', 1980],
  [9, 'Angela', 215, 'Girl', 1980],
  [10, 'Heather', 191, 'Girl', 1980],
  [10, 'Kimberly', 191, 'Girl', 1980],...
```

The expected output should be:

```
{ 'Amanda': [ [551, 'Girl', 1980],
          [[486, 'Girl', 1981]],
          [[567, 'Girl', 1982]],
          [[480, 'Girl', 1983]],
          [[457, 'Girl', 1984]]...
```

my actual output is:

```
{ 'Amanda': [ [551, 'Girl', 1980],
          [[486, 'Girl', 1981]],
          [[567, 'Girl', 1982]],
          [[480, 'Girl', 1983]],
          [[457, 'Girl', 1984]],
          [[551, 'Girl', 1980]],
          [[486, 'Girl', 1981]],
          [[567, 'Girl', 1982]],
          [[480, 'Girl', 1983]],
          [[457, 'Girl', 1984]],
          [[551, 'Girl', 1980]],
          [[486, 'Girl', 1981]],
          [[567, 'Girl', 1982]],
          [[480, 'Girl', 1983]],
          [[457, 'Girl', 1984]]],...
```

My code is this:

```
def create_names_dict(data_list, d):
    for row in data_list:
        if row[1] not in d: #if name not in dict
            d[row[1]] = ([row[2:]]) # make name a key and from freq on the val
        else:
            d[row[1]].append([row[2:]])
    return d #returned filled dict
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly are you intending to check here? `if row[2] not in d and row[4] not in d:`

Comment: I just used a snippet of the data list that has shows both genders. My list starts with the top ten boys names from 1980-1984 and then ends with the top ten girls names from 1980-1984. What I'm getting in my dictionary is the values repeating 3 times. I just want it from 1980-1984 ONE time instead of the three

Comment: can I change the expected output into `{'Amanda : {'1980' :[551, 'Girl'] ...` ?

Comment: It's supposed to return a list of lists for the key values, not a dictionary in a dictionary

Comment: `d` is an empty dictionary?

Comment: code doesn't make sense, what is the purpose of the `else` statement

Comment: from what I can see the OP  wants to keep only one info per year, as you can see same info it is duplicated

Comment: Yes d is an empty dictionary, sorry. Also the else statement was me just trying something new to fix it. I'm gonna edit it to the original, sorry again.

Comment: than can I drop him from parameters ? and use :  `create_names_dict(data_list)` ?

Comment: No, I need to have the empty dictionary as a requirement

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
def create_names_dict(data_list, d):
    for row in data_list:
        if row[1] not in r:
            d[row[1]] = {row[4] : row[2: 4]}
        elif row[4] not in d[row[1]]:
            d[row[1]][row[4]] = row[2: 4]
    return {k: [y + [i] for i, y in v.items()] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a dictionary to a function, any updates to the dictionary will be seen by the caller. Meaning that you don't have to return a dictionary, since you are already manipulating the dictionary that was passed.

Check out the .setdefault() method for a dictionary: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault

If the key exists, it will return the value. If they key doesn't exist, it will *insert* the key with the default value and return the newly set value. Your function can be simplified to:

```
def create_names_dict(data_list, d):
    for row in data_list:
        d.setdefault(row[1], []).append(row[2:])
```

Then:

```
d = {}
create_names_dict(l, d)
print(d)  # d is now populated with name -> [[freq, gender, year],...]
```

I suspect that you are getting duplicates because maybe you were calling `create_names_dict()` more than once and you were passing the dictionary so it happily appended data for the known keys. Or there could be duplicates in the input data, in which case you might have to do additional checks before appending.

Comment: Thank you for this, this helped very much. I found I was getting duplicates because I was indeed calling it more than once.. Now I feel silly lol.